# Call object.close() after running login script how ? function call inside test case

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans, testng

I am a selenium+testng tester in the making.
I have this codeigniter project.
i need to test the navigation.

What i have right now. 
I have tested togin script for the site.
but here is the thing when i try to run the second script it goes to login again. I can't blame the developers. But the problem is how to login each time using selenium in test cases.

=======================FILE 1 CLASS: common ========================

```
package common;    

/**
 *
 * @author Aruns
 */
public class common extends config {    

    public common() {

    }    

}
```

=====================FILE 2 CLASS:config ============================
==================== This is a config file ==========================

```
package common;    

/**
 *
 * @author Aruns
 */
public class config {    

    private final String base_url = "http://localhost/hospitalnew";
    private int timeout = 10;
    private String browser = "chrome";
    private final String chromeDriver = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\driver\\driver\\chromedriver.exe";
    private final String geckoDriver = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\driver\\driver\\firefoxdriver.exe";
    private final String ieDriver = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\driver\\driver\\operadriver.exe";
    private String currentUrl = "";
    private String currentTitle = "";
    private String username = "arun-reception";
    private String password = "arun";    

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }    

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }    

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }    

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }    

    public String getCurrentUrl() {
        return currentUrl;
    }    

    public void setCurrentUrl(String currentUrl) {
        this.currentUrl = currentUrl;
    }    

    public String getCurrentTitle() {
        return currentTitle;
    }    

    /**
     * sets current Title
     *
     * @param currentTitle = url
     */
    public void setCurrentTitle(String currentTitle) {
        this.currentTitle = currentTitle;
    }    

    public String getChromeDriver() {
        return chromeDriver;
    }    

    public String getGeckoDriver() {
        return geckoDriver;
    }    

    public String getIeDriver() {
        return ieDriver;
    }    

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }    

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }    

    public String getBase_url() {
        return base_url;
    }    

    public int getTimeout() {
        return timeout;
    }    

    public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }    

}
```

=======================FILE 3 CLASS:TestNavigationMenu===================

```
package critical;    

import common.common;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    

/**
 *
 * @author Aruns
 */
public class TestNavigationMenu {    

    public TestNavigationMenu() {
    }    

    // TODO add test methods here.
    // The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
    //
    // @Test
    // public void hello() {}
    WebDriver driver;
    common common;
    WebElement element;    

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }    

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }    

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
        common = new common();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", common.getChromeDriver());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(common.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }    

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDownMethod() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }    

    public void automatedlogin() throws Exception {
        String title = "Hospital Software  ";
        String url = "http://localhost/hospitalnew/appointment/appointments";    

        TestNavigationMenu object = new TestNavigationMenu();
        object.setUpMethod();    

        driver.navigate().to(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    

        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost/hospitalnew/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName__"));
        element.sendKeys(common.getUsername());    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("txtPass__"));
        element.sendKeys(common.getPassword());    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
        element.click();
    }    

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void login() throws Exception {
        String title = "Hospital Software  ";
        String url = "http://localhost/hospitalnew/appointment/appointments";    

        TestNavigationMenu object = new TestNavigationMenu();
        object.setUpMethod();    

        driver.navigate().to(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    

        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost/hospitalnew/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName__"));
        element.sendKeys(common.getUsername());    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("txtPass__"));
        element.sendKeys(common.getPassword());    

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
        element.click();    

        if (driver.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(url));
        }    

        object.tearDownMethod();    

    }

    // test case 3 
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void isWorkingMastersDepartment() throws Exception {
        String title = "Hospital Software  Department";
        String url = "http://localhost/hospitalnew/department/page";    


        automatedlogin();    

        driver.navigate().to(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    

        element = driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle"));
        element.click();    

        element = driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle"));
        element.click();    

        if (driver.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(url));
        }    

    }    

}
```

i though of making a function(automatic login) then calling it each time. But the problem is.
Chrome is ram intensive. opening lots of windows and not closing might cause problem in the long run. how to call object.close() for each run of testng+selenium test cases?

Secondly, i though of extending common to contain login script. But i don't know whether it will work properly.Please point me out.To the right direction.

And please grade my code if it was good for reading and optimised!

Thanks ~ 
         Arun

Comment: You should not be instantiating your own test to call the setup method: `TestNavigationMenu object = new TestNavigationMenu(); object.setUpMethod();`. TestNG will do that for you each time before running any test method, based on the `@BeforeMethod`. Similarly there's `@AfterMethod` to run your tear-down/cleanup logic (as well as before/after class, suite or group). You should probably [read a tutorial](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/) before jumping to development.

Comment: Regarding your code, you should also do a quick read on the [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) to improve readability and avoid confusion, eg your `common` & `config` classes should start with a capital letter. Also make sure the names you pick are meaningful. I may be able to understand what `Config` stands for, but `Common` does not really mean anything.

Comment: Thanks @Morfic i learned something new about setUpMethod and tearDown. Well common extends config its the same thing. I just kept them seperate for variables and functions(just in case). I changed the class name as stated.